# Data is not sent to Nodejs server on a simulated click

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax

Given the following code:

```
<form action="/map" method="POST" id="submitform">
    <input type="text" name="uid" id="UID"/>
</form>
    <button type="submit" id="toSubmit" form="submitform" value="submit" >Submit</button>
```

I have a function, that is perfectly working, that sends the data into this form and is clicking the "toSubmit" button.

```
function getData(uid) {
   document.getElementById("UID").value = uid;
   alert(document.getElementById("UID").value);
   document.getElementById("toSubmit").click();
}
```

Below a code snippet from the Node.js server;

```
router.post('/map', function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400);
    var id = req.body.uid;
    console.log(id);
});
```

The I'm using Node.js with express.js and body-parser.

In summary, the div is perfectly working if I submit the data without calling the `getData(uid)` function, just type in some input then click the button and the server received data, but when I try to make the div and the button `invisible(display:none;)` and use the function to simulate the click and send the data something is going wrong.

I think there may be a limitation problem with this `.click()` function.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to submit this using a name if the ID is not working..

```
<form name="formName" id="submitForm">
  <input type="text" />
</form>

function submitFormFunction(){
  document.formName.action="yourUrl";
  document.formName.submit();
}
```

Comment: Hi,I tried but I got the same result.The server isn't receiving the POST method but few GETs

Comment: the `method` attribute is missing from the form

Answer (score 0):

Rather than simulate a button click what you want to be doing for is simulating a form submit:

```
   document.getElementById("submitform").submit();
```

That should bundle all the names inputs and their data for you as you’d expect.

Depending on browser, you may also try:

```
    document.forms["submitform"].submit();
```

Comment: Hi,
Still not working...Now the function is:

    function getData(uid){
    document.getElementById("UID").value = uid;
    alert(document.getElementById("UID").value);
    document.getElementById("submitform").submit();
    //document.getElementById("toSubmit").click();
    }

Comment: What precisely is happening?

Comment: Data is set into the input field.And acording to your line of code the form should be submited.But the server doesn't receive the POST.Again,if i do the same thing manually everything works fine & the server is capable of reading this POST method but if i try to do it using .submit() or .click() nothing happens.

Comment: how are you calling getData()?

Comment: getData() is called from a MapBox script.But you don't have to worry about it,I get in the function,the alert is working,the data is asigned to the input field from the div and I did even an onclick="alert(smth)" for the button just to be sure it is clicked and yeah,it is,but I don't know why the data isn't sent to the server...